# SqlCommand with more than one result table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on an ASP.NET Web Application with Visual Studio 2010. My target framework is ".NET Framework 4" and I'm sending queries to a SQL Server 2008 database which version is "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2)".

I'm connecting using the following connection string `"Data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Integrated Security=False;User Id=XXXX;Password= XXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"` and sending queries with the code below:

```
public static List<DataTable> getData(String query)
{
    var results = new List<DataTable>();

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.CommandTimeout = 0;

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.executeReader())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        while (reader.Read()) ;
                        var dataTable = new DataTable();
                        dataTable.Load(reader);
                        results.Add(dataTable);
                    } while (reader.NextResult());
                }

                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The query I'm sending is an Stored Procedure which returns two tables, at first it had a loop which calls another Stored Procedure depending on some internal condition, creation and insertion on a `tempdb..#table` and two SELECT statements.

But now it only contains:

```
SELECT 1,2,3,4,5

SELECT 6,7,8,9,0
```

I don't know why but the `reader.NextResult()` is always false so I never get the second table result.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? What should I do to receive and read the two results from the query?

Comment: If you're wanting a `DataTable` why not use a [`SqlDataAdapter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.7.2) to populate the data table for you?

Comment: I don't want a `DataTable` I want an unknown number of `DataTables` that come along with the `SqlCommand` as result of the command.

Comment: That's a **really bad** interface to be offering to other parts of your code. The safest way to a) avoid formatting issues and b) avoid SQL Injection is to use *parameters* to pass data to the database system *separate* from any code that you're asking it to run. But that's impossible to do here where a single `string` is all that you're accepting.

Comment: a `DataSet` is the natural way to represent multiple `DataTable`s, and its `Load` method is already designed to consume multiple result sets, so far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the input string is just an example (it is a parametrized call to a procedure, sanitized to avoid injection) but (for now) the security is not the issue I'm facing.

Comment: you seem to forget you are calling a stored proc - see answer below

Comment: you do not need `while (reader.Read()) ;` here, `dataTable.Load(reader);` will works just fine.

Comment: You're right in one thing: I don't need the empty while loop. You're (slightly) wrong in one thing: `dataTable.Load(reader)` works fine, but it only reads one result table, when code flow hits the `while (reader.NextResult())` it jumps out of the loop.

Comment: Can you try same stuff with a Micro ORM like Dapper, which offers QueryMultiple for same purpose and does a great job in fetching multiple result sets, ultimately it would offer same APIs internally and verification will help in narrowing down on the issue, which seems to be data client specific.
[Dapper Micro ORM](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if this is using a stored proc you need something like this: **notice the command type**

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(myConnString))
{
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "myMultipleTablesSP";
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        conn.Open();

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

if for example you return 2 tables in your SP, like:

```
SELECT * FROM [TableA];
SELECT * FROM [TableB];
```

you would access this tables as:

```
DataTable tableA = ds.Tables[0];
DataTable tableB = ds.Tables[1];
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Still I don't know why it doesn't work with my first approach, any clue?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have run some test and find out the problem is from `dataTable.Load(reader);` somehow and I don't know why and what is exactly happening behind that method.
but if you use

```
do {
   while(reader.Read()) {
      ...
   }
} while (reader.NextResult());
```

everything works as expected.